# Android Activity: Start new activity or bring to front old one?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

Currently I'm writing my "Hello world" app and I've noticed in my log that everytime I start an activity, new instance is created. My app consists of two activities. At one activity you enter select query for your database and in the second one is displayed the result of your query in listview. Since the result of the query could be like 100k in my conditions, it seems to me a bit overhead to populate another listview everytime I enter new select.

**Is it ok to just create a new activity or is it better to bring the old one to front?**

Comment: I think you should start new activity as data is always different...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to populate the `ListView` every time anyway, as the results of the query are different. The nice thing about `ListView` is that it only creates a handful of `View` objects (enough to fill the screen) even if you give it hundreds or thousands of items to display.

Besides, "populating" the `ListView` is just adding objects to an array. No big deal.

Comment: "The nice thing about ListView is that it only creates a handful of View objects (enough to fill the screen)" I'm not sure about this one, but I guess that this is what Adapter does.

Comment: Anyway, you're right. When you create a listview, you fill the data into some object (array or list). If you want to reuse listview, then you have to throw away the object with the data and put there new object with new data. So it's almost the same as starting new activity. I just forgot that programing for Android "is" programing in Java.